# Why is my escalation rule NOT ignoring holidays?

Tags: holidays

I have an escalation rule setup as follows:

```
Rule Name: Idle Notification
Active: Checked
```

I only have 1 rule entry and it has the following attributes:

```
Rule Criteria: (Case: Status not equal to Closed) and (Case: Case Owner equals ExampleQueue)
Business Hours Settings: Set business hours on case with "Default"
How escalation times are set: Based on when the case is created.
```

I have 1 escalation action:

```
Age over: 2 Hours 00 Minutes
Additional emails: foo@foo.com
```

I also added my company holidays under Company Profile -> Holidays.

My understanding is that the escalation rule should NOT trigger during company holidays because that should be excluded.  And yet, it DOES trigger.  Why is this?

Comment: did you assign those holidays to a business hours record? you do it via the related list on holidays or business hours

Comment: @Eric Bingo.  I think that was it.  Testing now.

Comment: adding as an answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely will need to assign those holidays to a business hours record. you do it via the related list on holidays or business hours